# Using ByteArrayInputStream instead of FileInputStream

Tags: java, google-app-engine

**Context**

I am adapting parts of an existing project to a gae project. The original project uses `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` but since gae doesn't accept `FileOutputStream` I am replacing them with `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream`. The original code loaded some local files and I replaced those with `Datastore Entities` that hold the content of those files in one of their properties.

**Problem**

It mostly seems to work but I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in this piece of code:

```
private byte[] loadKey(Entity file) {
        byte[] b64encodedKey = null;
        ByteArrayInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = fileToStreamAdapter.objectToInputStreamConverter(file);
            b64encodedKey = new byte[(int) fis.available()];
            fis.read(b64encodedKey);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null)
                    fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return b64encodedKey;
    }
```

`fileToStreamAdapter.objectToInputStreamConverter(file)` takes a `Datastore Entity` and turns the content of one of its properties into a `ByteArrayInputStream`.

The original code:

```
private byte[] loadKey(String path) {
        byte[] b64encodedKey = null;
        File fileKey = new File(path);
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(fileKey);
            b64encodedKey = new byte[(int) fileKey.length()];
            fis.read(b64encodedKey);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null)
                    fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return b64encodedKey;
    }
```

Is there something I'm missing in the differences between `FileInputStream` and `ByteArrayInputStream` that could cause this error?

Comment: What is the exception stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that if `objectToInputStreamConverter` created the `ByteArrayInputStream` using [ByteArrayInputStream(byte[] buf)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#ByteArrayInputStream-byte:A-) then it could just return the byte[] argument and save you from the need to read anything more, not to mention all that error handling.

Comment: You were right, by wanting to stick to the original code I did some unnecessary steps. In the end I just had to take the content from the Entity and turn that into a Byte[].

Answer (score 0):

`fis.available()` is not the size of the input stream, just how much data available in the buffer at this point.

If you need to return bytes from input stream you have to copy it by using something like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int l;
byte[] data = new byte[16384];
while ((l = fis.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
  buffer.write(data, 0, l);
}
buffer.flush();
return buffer.toByteArray();
```

Or better us `IOUtils` from `commons-io`